# How to scale my Horizontal-axis labels in chart.js Version 4.4.0

Tags: chart.js

I have data should represent data in a line chart where X-axis represents time in milliseconds.
however, the labels are decimal values and i want to visualize as integers with step size of 10.

I tried putting (options.scales[x].ticks.stepsize: 10), but it didn't work.

can someone please help me out with this, I am stuck.

I want to my chart to display x-Axis as [0,10,20,30,....100] with all data corresponding to y-axis falling in this range.

the following is the data to be represented in the line chart

```js
        var ImpData = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [0.0001,2.5,5.0001,7.5,12.5,15.0001,17.5,20.0001,22.5,25.0001,27.5,30.0001,32.5,35.0001,37.5,40.0001,42.5,45.0001,47.5,50.0001,52.5,55.0001,57.5,60.0001,62.5,65.0001,67.5,70.0001,72.5,75.0001,77.5,80.0001,82.5,85.0001,87.5,90.0001,92.5,95.0001,97.5],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'ix',
                        data: [-7.0200000000000005,-7.0200000000000005,-6.24,-6.24,-5.46,-4.68,-4.68,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.12,-2.34,39.0001,-3.12,31.98,44.46,28.080000000000002,10.92,3.12,-3.12,-7.800000000000001,-10.14,-9.36,-7.800000000000001,-6.24,-4.68,-2.34,0.0001,0.78,2.34,2.34,1.56,0.78,0.0001,-0.78,-7.800000000000001,-7.800000000000001,-7.800000000000001],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(168, 218, 220, 0.5)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(168, 218, 220, 0.5)',
                        yAxisID: 'y1'
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                plugins:{
                    title:{
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Impact (g)',
                        color: 'black',
                        font:{
                            size: '16px',
                            weight: 'bold'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        labels:{
                            color: 'black'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: false
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'TIME',
                            align: 'center',
                            color: 'black',
                            font:{
                                size: '18px',
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            color: 'black',
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            stepSize: 10,
                            font: {
                                size: '18px',
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    y1: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Acceleration',
                            align: 'center',
                            color: 'black',
                            font:{
                                size: '18px',
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            color: 'black',
                            font: {
                                size: '18px',
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also declare the `type` of the x axis, as `linear`. It is a slightly odd feature of `chart.js` that the axis types, if not specified, are the default for the chart type. And since your chart type is `line`, the `indexAxis`, which is `x`, is of type `category`.

We can read at the chart type `scatter` that it is almost the same with `line`, with the exception of the default properties and the fact that the index line is of type `linear`.

> The scatter chart supports all the same properties as the line chart. By default, the scatter chart will override the showLine property of the line chart to false. [...]
> The index scale is of the type linear.

So one solution would be to change the type of the chart to `scatter`; that would however require you to also teak with the point and line options. In any case, the `scatter` type seems to have been designed for the plots of scientific of the type you have.

And again, the simplest solution is to jsut declare your axis type as `linear`:

```js
var ImpData = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [0.0001,2.5,5.0001,7.5,12.5,15.0001,17.5,20.0001,22.5,25.0001,27.5,30.0001,32.5,35.0001,37.5,40.0001,42.5,45.0001,47.5,50.0001,52.5,55.0001,57.5,60.0001,62.5,65.0001,67.5,70.0001,72.5,75.0001,77.5,80.0001,82.5,85.0001,87.5,90.0001,92.5,95.0001,97.5],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'ix',
                data: [-7.0200000000000005,-7.0200000000000005,-6.24,-6.24,-5.46,-4.68,-4.68,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.9000000000000004,-3.12,-2.34,39.0001,-3.12,31.98,44.46,28.080000000000002,10.92,3.12,-3.12,-7.800000000000001,-10.14,-9.36,-7.800000000000001,-6.24,-4.68,-2.34,0.0001,0.78,2.34,2.34,1.56,0.78,0.0001,-0.78,-7.800000000000001,-7.800000000000001,-7.800000000000001],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(168, 218, 220, 0.5)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(168, 218, 220, 0.5)',
                yAxisID: 'y1'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        plugins:{
            title:{
                display: true,
                text: 'Impact (g)',
                color: 'black',
                font:{
                    size: '16px',
                    weight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                labels:{
                    color: 'black'
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'TIME',
                    align: 'center',
                    color: 'black',
                    font:{
                        size: '18px',
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    color: 'black',
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    stepSize: 10,
                    font: {
                        size: '18px',
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
            y1: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Acceleration',
                    align: 'center',
                    color: 'black',
                    font:{
                        size: '18px',
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    color: 'black',
                    font: {
                        size: '18px',
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
new Chart('myChart', ImpData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for the your quick response and your suggestion worked for my case and it is better than what I tried today!

I also found another method using callbacks which does the same thing except it hides the label of a specified index

however, the view is not exactly same compared as yours. here is the code:

options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        callback: fucntion(val, index){
          return index%5 === 0 ? Math.round(this.getLabelForValue(val)) : '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}